# Laravel Backpack Fusioncharts widget not working

Tags: php, laravel, chart.js, laravel-backpack, fusioncharts

I have a Laravel app that uses backpack and I am trying to create a chart with bars that when clicked, will redirect you to a specific CRUD page on the site. I did a little research and figured out that Fusioncharts (one of the charting libraries listed on the [Laravel Backpack Chart Widget Documentation](https://backpackforlaravel.com/docs/6.x/base-widgets#chart-pro)) supports adding a "link" property to the data.

I am trying to create a page with an example Fusionchart Chart, but it only renders a box that says "Loading chart. Please wait."

**My Chart Controller:**

```
<?php

declare(strict_types=1);

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Charts;

use Backpack\CRUD\app\Http\Controllers\ChartController;
use ConsoleTVs\Charts\Classes\Fusioncharts\Chart;

class ExampleChartController extends ChartController
{
    public function setup(): void
    {
        $this->chart = new Chart();
        $this->chart->labels(['Label 1', 'Label 2', 'Label 3']);
        $this->chart->load(backpack_url('charts/example'));
    }

    public function data(): void
    {
        $this->chart->dataset('Group 1', 'bar', [1, 2, 3]);
    }
}
```

The chart renders correctly when I change the import to `use ConsoleTVs\Charts\Classes\Chartjs\Chart;` instead of `use ConsoleTVs\Charts\Classes\Fusioncharts\Chart;`

Can anyone help me get this chart working, or let me know if it's even possible to add links to bars using Backpack Widgets? Thanks.

Comment: You do understand that this consoletvs/charts package is just a convenience layer to work with JS charting libraries? You can't just change the PHP code without also loading the appropriate front end library.

Comment: @miken32 How might I do that? I tried adding the scripts that they show [here](https://www.fusioncharts.com/blog/a-step-by-step-guide-to-charts/) to my blade file in an `@push('after_scripts')` and it didn't work

Comment: I stopped working with it a few years ago so I can't say. But you need to ensure the front end scripting is working or nothing you change in the PHP code will make any difference.